# How to change color of text inside ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, navigation-drawer

How can i change color of ListView Text(in drawer layout) in my code?
In my code listview is in various other layout.
I have tried various other code available in stackoverflow but none seemed to work for me

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lltoolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lltoolbar"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />


</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:entries="@array/abcd"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

---

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
TextView textView;
ImageView iv;
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ListView listView;
private String[] names;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivClick);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);       

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
    names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.abcd);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should create an xml layout for each row of your listview then create a class extend BaseAdapter and inside of getview inflate xml layout then set color for textview

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Create an xml layout which will be shown in each row of your listview. (currently you are using the default android.R.layout.simple_list-item_1 layout)  something like this:
   **my_listrow_layout.xml:**

> ```
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:orientation="vertical">
> <TextView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="sample text"
>         android:text_color="#006699"
>         android:id="@+id/list_item"/>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```
>
> 2. in your activity code, change your list adapter code to this:
>
> ```
> listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.my_listrow_layout,
> R.id.list_item, names));
> ```

my_listrow_layout is your custom made layout for the listview, R.id.list_item is the id of your textview in the listview layout. To change the color of the text add android:text_color="your desired color" value in the layout you just created. ( I have set it to #006699 which a dark blue color).